# How to get position of footer image and set for box using slidetoggle

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a image with a box message. I want click in image then slidetoggle box message under the image, but when I click the image then the box show behind the image although I have set z-index for css. When I check position of the box, the box get positon with my banner not with div tag it inner. How can I set position of footer of image and set it for the box always under image?

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5cols">
                    <div id="service" class="thumbnail">
                        <a class="activatorService" id="activatorService">
                            <img id="imgService" src="./img/01.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="boxService" id="boxService">
                    <a class="boxcloseService" id="boxcloseService"></a>
                    <h4 style="font-family: Futura; color:  #333333; font-weight: bold; size: 30pt;">My solutions</h4>
                    <p style="margin: 0; font-family: Avenir; size: 20pt; color: #5e5e5e;">Hello World</p>
                </div>
```

Comment: Can u please make a codepen or something like this ?

Answer (score 0):

I`m not sure, if I understood you correctly.
boxService should show when you click on image, click again and box will be hidden? If so, add to your css file

```
#boxService {
  display: none;
}
```

And add jQuery with this pice of code:

```
$( "#imgService" ).click(function() {
  $( "#boxService" ).toggle( "slow" );
});
```